# UWP - Data Annotations

Tags: c#, sqlite, data-annotations, uwp

Model:

```
class BlaBla
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {2} and {1}.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u01ff]([\s]?))+$", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not in the correct format.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,2}.\d$", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not in the correct format.")]
    public float Meterage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I ran the code and it's fine. The table BlaBla was created on SQLite (look below) without problems, but without any constraints, why? What am I doing wrong?

The code that was generated in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE "BlaBla"(
"Id" integer primary key autoincrement not null ,
"Name" varchar ,
"Meterage" float ,
"Date" datetime );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "BlaBla_Id" on "BlaBla"("Id");
```

I suppose it must set everything to "NOT NULL" and with the maximum number of characters.

Comment: What Sqlite library are you using?

Comment: @KenTucker well, I was not using SQLite library for these properties. Just SQLite.Net for the [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]. I was trying to using ComponentModel.DataAnnonations of C#, is it possible?

Comment: I know I can use [NotNull] and [MaxLength] of SQLite,Net, but I can't write messages to display errors into it.

Comment: if you want to use the required I would look at using ef7 instead of sqlite-net http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html

Comment: But EF7 isn't in final release yet..There's no problem to use SQLite.Net, what I want know is how to display those error messages of Model on View. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the SQLite.NET wrappers does not have any "Required" attribute and its NotNull attribute doesn't have any Message property.

If you want to display error messages on "Insert" operations I think you would have to implement some custom solution or use another ORM/SQLite library.

You can check the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/tree/master/src/SQLite.Net/Attributes) to see all the supported attributes.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. I already know about SQLinet.Net properties, but I thought I could use the DataAnnotations properties, anyway, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that SQLite.NET process only its own attributes, so you have to modifiy its sources if you want to use DataAnnotations.